# How do I draw points through a for loop in HTML Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

So I want to make a function that allows me to create 20 random points and draw them on a canvas. Below is the code I currently am working with.

So my code did work when I had it return points in literal text number form, yet when I try to make it draw points, nothing happens at all. Is it because the random code itself is wrong, or am I making a mistake with the canvas?

```
function randomPoints(){

    var z = 20;
    var z1;
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
        ctx.beginPath();
    for (z1 = 0; z1<z; z1++){

        var i = new Point(Math.floor((Math.random() * 1200)), Math.floor((Math.random() * 700)));


        ctx.arc(a.x,a.y,10,0,2*Math.PI);
        ctx.fillStyle = '#000000';
        ctx.fill();

    }


}
```

the 1200 and 700 is the size of the canvas.

Comment: where is your `Point` class? could that be the problem? it also appears that the object `a` is undefined and you are not calling the function after it is declared

Comment: If you add `"use strict";` to the top of your JavaScript [the JavaScript console](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/) will likely show you an error in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are my observations:

1. Your "random" code is correct
2. The `Point()` class may not be supported by the browser
3. Use a better "point" with `fillRect`
4. Use the `fillStyle` first so that it affects the `fillRect`
5. Make the function re-usable for number and colors

Here is the code:

```
function randomPoints(canvas, count, color){
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1200);
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 700);
    canvas.fillStyle = color;
    canvas.fillRect(x,y,10,10);
  }
}
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
randomPoints(ctx, 20, 'red');
randomPoints(ctx, 5, 'blue');
```

This [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-e6vwv8?embed=1&file=index.js) shows a working example to help you get along.

Comment: Did you consider using a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to make the code live and runnable in the question itself?